# Custom installer for a .net application

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I need to create a custom installer that supports French, German, Spanish, Italian, Polish, Russian, English, chinese (mandarin script), more languages to be added for a .net based application.

This installer also needs to be able to check whether the target system has got adobe installed or not. If the target system doesnt have adobe or is a lower version than required then it should install from the CD. if it does then bypass that step.

The installer also needs to prompt the user to browse to any location on the system to pick up a file which will be place in the installation folder.

The installer also need to register this program in the add remove programs list.

Is there a custom installer that can do all of these tasks or do I need to build an application from scratch for it?

Thoughts... ideas???

Thanks for your time...

Comment: You could take a look at Wix for building a custom installer. http://wix.sourceforge.net/

Comment: there doesnt seem to be any documentation I can find on the site. I need to justify its usefulness before I can seek approval for its download on the corp network.. sadly!

Comment: That's unfortunate. There is some documentation at that link but wix in general is woefully under-documented. It's basically a collection of tools that compile an XML file into a windows installer. It's quite fiddly to work with but allows you to make incredibly customisable installers. If I was doing what you say you want to do it's most likely what I'd use.

Comment: Take a look at [WiX Tutorial](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/). It can help you understand what it does and how it works, more or less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer : Yes, all those things can be done, most of them easily.

WiX or NSIS are probably your two best *free* options. NSIS uses a plugin architecture for most of it's functionality, but the plugins are text-files, so you should have no problems downloading them. However, if your company is "funny" about licensing, then check the relevant licenses for each plugin early on - most are completely free to use, but Legal can fail to understand this sometimes...

Please find below pointers to the relevant sections of the documentation, so you can get it downloaded (I feel your pain by the way!)

#### Language Support

See [Docs](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Creating_language_files_and_integrating_with_MUI#)

#### Allow user to select a file and copy it

You will need the [InstallOptions](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/InstallOptions/Readme.html) plugin. This allows you to create an extra page in your install wizard which can prompt for information. It allows various controls, one of which is a file explorer control (search for `FileRequest` in the link).

To copy the file, you cannot simply use the `File` instruction, as that *extracts and copies* files from the installation media, and will not act on files on the target computer.

Instead, you will need a plugin - e.g. [this wrapper](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/WinAPI%3akernel32%3aCopyFile) around the WinAPI. Alternatively, use the [CopyFiles](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.3.2) instruction.

#### Register program in Add/Remove programs

This is standard in both WiX and NSIS.

#### Detect Adobe is installed.

NSIS has the ability to check if registry keys exist, or named files exist, which are the two normal methods of detecting installed programs.

Comment: WiX also supports localization, custom dialogs in the UI, and searching for related applications through registry keys, file system.

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest WiX couldn't do these things. I'm just more familiar with NSIS, and WiX had been addressed in the comments. Really, all of these things are bread-and-butter for any reasonably mature installer technology.

Comment: Of course! You mentioned WiX, yet the rest of the answer was mostly about NSIS. So I decided to add a comment to make it clear WiX has these features too. I didn't mean to sound as if you said it didn't.

Comment: ok once I have the UI prompt the user for a file location. I need that file selected to move to the installation directory. How is that done?. Thats what I am trying to work out now. If any of you know that in NSIS.. or if someone has an example in WIX ..either ways is ok for me at this time :)

Comment: Updated answer with two solutions.